# Adding methods to an JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

I could create an object with some methods, and later add a property to it as follows:

```
var myObj = (function () {
    var my = {};
    my.method1=function(){}
    my.method2=function(){}
    my.method3=function(){}
    return my;
    }());
myObj.myProperty=123;
```

How could I create the object first and add a property, and then later add the methods afterwards?

```
myObj={};
myObj.myProperty=123;
//How do I add the above methods to myObj?
```

Comment: `myObj.my = { method1: function() }`

Comment: Why can't you use `myObj.method1 = function() {}`?

Comment: I assume you are not simply doing `myObj.method1=function(){};` because you want the functions to be defined in their own scope? Otherwise I don't really see what the issue is.

Comment: @FelixKling  Yes, each of them have their own script.

Comment: @ShawnBush  I suppose I could, but the way I showed just seemed like a clean way to organize them.

Comment: @tymeJV  Please elaberate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are two solutions:

Merge the objects:

```
var myObj = {...};
// ...
var objWithMethods = (function() { ... }());
Object.assign(myObj, objWithMethods);
```

([**`Object.assign`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is an ES6 methods. A polyfill can be found in the link, libraries often also provide a method with similar behavior).

Pass the object the methods should be assigned to as argument:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj = (function (obj) {
    var my = obj || {};
    my.method1=function(){}
    my.method2=function(){}
    my.method3=function(){}
    return my;
}(myObj));
```

Comment: Thank you Felix.  Would you recommend one approach over the other?  I assume I will go the with the second option unless you think differently.

Comment: At this point, the most important factor is that whoever reads the code understands what's going on.

Comment: Well, I definitely understand the second approach, but currently not the first approach.  Suppose I should learn both of them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do an extend operation using an existing object

```
var myObj = {...}

var myAdditionalMethods = { someMethod : function(){ } }

//extend the object
for(var i in myAdditionalMethods)
   if(!myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) 
       myObj[i] = myAdditionalMethods[i];
```

there are a lot of libraries that have this functionality built in, but that is how you would do it without one

Answer (score 0):

Even prototype can add the functions to original object.

```js
 var myObj = function() {
   this.myProperty = 123;
 }

 myObj.prototype.method1 = function method1() {
   alert("method1")
 }
 myObj.prototype.method2 = function method2() {
   alert("method2")
 }
 var newObj = new myObj();
 newObj.method1();
 newObj.method2();
 console.log(newObj)
```